# How to check and compare user input from console?

Tags: c#, class, interface, console-application, user-input

I have been trying to make a simple program to check a person's birthday and if their birthday is the same as their pet, for it to be printed out on the console, or if it's not the same to type out no valid input. I don't know why but the variables are not being taken in saying they aren't properly added or it just says they need a get/set. If anyone could show and explain how it should be done it would be like really awesome and cool and amazing. Here's the code:

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Human human = new Human();
            human.name();
            human.age();
            human.id();
            human.birthday();


            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.id();
            robot.model();


            Pet pet = new Pet();
            pet.name();
            pet.birthday();

            Program program = new Program();
            program.BirthdayCheck("","");
            

        }
        public static void BirthdayCheck(string userResponse1, string userResponse2)
        {
            if (userResponse1 == userResponse2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("" + userResponse1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No matching birthday");
            }
            
        }



        interface IHuman
        {
            void name();
            void age();
            void id();
            void birthday();

        }

        interface IRobot
        {
            void model();
            void id();
        }

        interface IPet
        {
            void name();
            void birthday();
        }

        class Human : IHuman
        {
            public string userResponse2;

            public string Birthday
            {
                get { return userResponse2; }
                set { userResponse2 = value; }
            }
            public void name()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Citizen name: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            public void age()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Citizen's age: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            public void id()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Citizen's id: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            public void birthday()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Citizen's birthday: ");
                userResponse2 = Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }

        class Robot : IRobot
        {

            public void model()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Robot Model: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            public void id()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Robot Id: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        class Pet : IPet
        {

            public string userResponse1;

            public string Birthday
            {
                get { return userResponse1; }
                set { userResponse1 = value; }
            }
            public void name()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter pet name: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            public void birthday()

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter pet birthday: ");
                userResponse1 = Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had no issues with the interfaces themselves and it does that the information, it just doesn't want to compare the two between them. I don't know if it's just a logical or syntax error, but hopefully, it's at least partially correct. Finished up some syntax errors but the issues still remain. The error message that appears is "Member Program.BitrhdayCheck(string, string) cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead."

Comment: Is it a typo? You have just forgotten `()` after `BirthdayCheck`.

Comment: Many syntax errors: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4oi3BA. As @SNBS mentions, you're missing the `()` after `BirthdayCheck`, but also, that function is not closed before the interface definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above, this looks like a really complicated program to compare something so simple. Assuming that's your choice, I think these two lines in the main method are not quite correct:

```
            Program program = new Program();
            program.BirthdayCheck("","");
```

you really should be calling the `BirthdayCheck` method directly.
Another issue is, no value is really being passed to this method. So not sure exactly what is it you're comparing.

---

Here's a fix to your main method that can solve your issue:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Human human = new Human();
        human.name();
        human.age();
        human.id();
        human.birthday();


        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.id();
        robot.model();


        Pet pet = new Pet();
        pet.name();
        pet.birthday();

        BirthdayCheck(pet.Birthday, human.Birthday); // birthdaycheck is method of the program class, hence does not need to be invoked with a new program object. 
// Additionally, you need to pass an actual birthday value to compare instead of blank strings. 

        Console.ReadKey(); // this step ensures the console does not close after the birthday check
    }
    public static void BirthdayCheck(string userResponse1, string userResponse2)
    {
        if (userResponse1 == userResponse2)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("" + userResponse1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No matching birthday");
        }

    }
```

Here's an output sample of the program after the above mentioned changes:

```
Citizen name:
w
Citizen's age:
12
Citizen's id:
1
Citizen's birthday:
10/10/1990
Enter Robot Id:
2
Enter Robot Model:
r2d2
Enter pet name:
p2v2
Enter pet birthday:
11/11/1991
No matching birthday
```

Comment: I tried doing it directly but it just says I cannot convert from method group to bool.

Answer (score 0):

userResponse1 and userResponse2 are out of scope from the BirthdayCheck method. you need to either pass in references to the human/pet objects(like human.userResponse2 == pet.userResponse1) or pass the birthdays themselves in to compare.

Comment: How would you do that? Do you mind showing the passing of the reference? It can either be the objects or the birthday itself.

Comment: sure thing, you need to change the method declaration: for objects `BirthdayCheck(Human h, Pet p){... if(h.userResponse2) == p.userResponse1}`  for passing the birthdays in directly `BirthdayCheck(String userResponse1, String userResponse2){...}`

Comment: Did it just now! It's taking the user input, but it still says that "BirthdayCheck" doesn't return a value. Why does it do that? Isn't the console write line with a value in it?

Comment: you declared it as `public string BirthdayCheck` but then you don't have a return statement. try declaring it as `public void BirthdayCheck`

Comment: Hmm, it now doesn't return anything. It just comes up empty nothing pops up.

Comment: It shows no errors but nothing returns at all, is it because it's void, or what? I edited the post so you can see the full code if it helps.

Comment: That's right, if you declare a method as returning void, then that means you intend it to return nothing. It comes down to how you need your program to work. You'll have to put the console.writeline logic in the main method and have BirthdayCheck return a string to do it the other way. Also, you never actually call birthdaycheck anywhere, so the code never runs at runtime

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding it into the main but I just get errors left and right about the object not being able to switch to string.

Comment: try keeping it the way it was with BirthdayCheck declared as void but this time make sure you call BirthdayCheck in the main method. you should get at least some console output if you do that.

Comment: pleae add the exact error message to the post

Comment: I added the exact error message at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you made this so complicated?
You made 3 classes and 3 interfaces and how do you expect them to work together?
You use Console.WriteLine(); without variables.

Does your code need to make sense? If its just for practice, you should
slow down and try something more simple, like 2 classes and then compare,
then 2 classes and 1 interface and then compare...

Comment: Well to tell the truth It's basically just a recycled program from an older assignment. It's the same in nature only real difference is having the user input which is what I am currently struggling with. And yeah sadly it must be this complicated, it requires the interfaces to exist with the objects, however, they are never used.

Answer (score -1):

you mean

```
    public string BirthdayCheck()
    {
```

you were missing () from the method declaration

Comment: We have a close reason for typos...

Comment: Yeah, my bad just forgot it, however, it still pops up wrong. It's now saying that the user response doesn't exist in the current context.